# How to make RTK Query cache a 404 response, just like a 200?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, rtk-query

My application fetches data from an API with RTK Query. This data may contain references (ID's) to entities, which may trigger additional queries. Sometimes, those referenced entities do not exist anymore. When retrieving such a non-existing entity, the API returns a 404.

A useQuery hook returns cached data immediately, while fresh data is being fetched. However I believe that 404 responses are not cached like the data from a 200 response. When you call the useQuery hook with the ID of a non-existing entity, the same API request is made, but I don't get an initial cached value saying "last time we tried this ID, we got a 404". This causes flashing in the rendered component, because I can only render the fallback value once the 404 has been fetched.

What can I do to make RTK Query "remember" that a certain ID has returned a 404, and provide that information to the component immediately?

Comment: To whoever voted to close: feel free to clarify, I'm happy to learn and improve my question.